# Can't remove a JFrame's added components on mouseclick

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to have a button remove all elements from a JFrame so I can add new ones. However, when I click the button, the frame gets frozen and nothing is removed. I've created this minimal example:

```
public class Main {
    static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        JButton b = new JButton("Die");
        b.addActionListener(e -> {
             die();
        });

        frame.add(b);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void die(){
        frame.removeAll();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: You should build separate `JPanels` and show them in turn with a main `JPanel` using a `CardLayout`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: Used a CardLayout and it works fine now, thank you